# How to enroll image on Kairos Cloud using Java?

Tags: java, kairos-api

I am using Kairos API, for face recognized. I want to upload image on Kairos Cloud. I got an error one or more subject required. Bellow My code

```
//passing from jsp page
MultipartFile file = enoroll.getImage();
byte[] image = file.getBytes();
getId = 102;
                String imageString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(image);

                imageString.replaceAll("\"", "\"");
                Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
                @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
                Entity payload = Entity.json("{  \"image\": \"" + imageString + "\",  \"subject_id\": \"" + getId
                        + "\",  \"gallery_name\": \"test\"}");
                Response response = client.target("https://api.kairos.com/enroll")
                        .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).header("app_id", "3624f882")
                        .header("app_key", "f2e9b87b4ae5d406ae704973563100e9").post(payload);
```

Comment: can you post error screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer [Kairos Sample](https://kairos.docs.apiary.io/#reference/face-recognition/enroll/post)

```
    import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
    import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
    import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    Entity payload = Entity.json("{  'image': 'http://media.kairos.com/kairos- 
 elizabeth.jpg',  'subject_id': 'Elizabeth',  'gallery_name': 'MyGallery'}");
   Response response = client.target("https://api.kairos.com/enroll")
  .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
  .header("app_id", "4985f625")
  .header("app_key", "aa9e5d2ec3b00306b2d9588c3a25d68e")
  .post(payload);

System.out.println("status: " + response.getStatus());
System.out.println("headers: " + response.getHeaders());
System.out.println("body:" + response.readEntity(String.class));
```

Comment: **http://media.kairos.com/kairos-elizabeth.jpg**  they are giving directly link of image. You can convert image to base64 format and pass there